# Mass Spectrometry Data Analysis

Tags: data, r

I'm currently in the process of writing a program in R to perform analysis of data from a mass spectrometry experiment. Well, that's the idea. I'm fairly new to R, and didn't actually perform the mass spec experiment myself, so I'm encountering a few problems.

Essentially, I have a set of m/z (mass/charge ratio) values, from which I need to extract mass peaks.

Now, I can just about perform the necessary integration to obtain the desired results from the mass peaks, and even put that information into pretty graphs. The key problem is with actually finding the mass peaks to begin with. Each mass peak has an m/z value of 744.68 +/- 0.02, and several nearby values which are greater by up to 0.333... m/z units.

Here's my problem. If I want to find something, I would generally use *gregexpr*, but I'm not looking for any one specific value, I'm looking for all the values within a certain range which fit a certain pattern.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try look for "subsetting" with tag `[r]` on Stack Overflow, [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+subsetting). Regarding the potentially unlimited possibilities of values, the experiment should come with a list of possible species (molecules, ions, radicals, fragments). Each species can then have charge 0, +/-1, +/-2, and so on.

Comment: Or are you trying to do an integral (summation) of measurements over a subset of (m/z) values?